# Can't get past "undefined reference to `XXXX'"

Tags: c++, linker, fortran

I'm currently writing a header-only wrapper library which is supposed to provide C++ access to some FORTRAN code. But I'm stuck at the 'undefined reference (...)'

I must say I'm a little bit surprised because I compiled my own functions in C++ using this FORTRAN routine, with no problems at all.

Maybe a few words about the structure. The library follows the singleton pattern, but without the possibility of instantiating the Library by the user. So the only entry point for the user is a static method `MultiNestWrapper::Wrapper<T>::run()`. `MultiNestWrapper` is a namespace, `Wrapper<T>` is a templated class (so that in future you can benchmark how choosing on which type to perform calculations affects results and performance). The FORTRAN routine is declared outside of this namespace, as

```
extern "C" {
  extern void __nested_MOD_nestrun(int *, int *, int *, double *, double *, int *, int *, int *, int *, int *, double *, const char *, int *, int *, int *, int *, void (*Loglike)(double *, int *, int *, double *), void (*dumper)(int *, int *, int *, double **, double **, double *, double *, double *), int *context);
}
```

and I call it like

```
__nested_MOD_nestrun(&_mmodal, &_ceff, &_nlive, &_tol, &_efr, &_ndims, &_nPar, &_nClsPar, &_maxModes, &_updInt, &_Ztol, _root, &_seed, _pWrap, &_fb, &_resume, internalLogLike, internalDumper, &_context);
```

And the types for arguments match.

When I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
[dare2be@schroedinger multinest-interfejs]$ make all
g++ -c ExampleLibMnCpp.cpp -o ExampleLibMnCpp.o
gfortran -lstdc++ -llapack -lblas -lnest3 -L/usr/local/lib ExampleLibMnCpp.o -o ExampleLibMnCpp
ExampleLibMnCpp.o: In function `MultiNestWrapper::Wrapper<double>::run(MultiNestWrapper::MNParams<double>*, double (*)(double const*, int), bool, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, double, int, double, void (*)(int*, int*, int*, double**, double**, double*, double*, double*), int, double, bool)':
ExampleLibMnCpp.cpp:(.text._ZN16MultiNestWrapper7WrapperIdE3runEPNS_8MNParamsIdEEPFdPKdiEbSsididPFvPiS9_S9_PPdSB_SA_SA_SA_Eidb[MultiNestWrapper::Wrapper<double>::run(MultiNestWrapper::MNParams<double>*, double (*)(double const*, int), bool, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, double, int, double, void (*)(int*, int*, int*, double**, double**, double*, double*, double*), int, double, bool)]+0x585): undefined reference to `__nested_MOD_nestrun'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ExampleLibMnCpp] Error 1
```

But, note that

```
[dare2be@schroedinger multinest-interfejs]$ nm /usr/local/lib/libnest3.a | grep __nested_MOD_nestrun
000000000001e0f0 T __nested_MOD_nestrun
```

I've always dealt with those undefined references myself. But now I can't wrap my head around this. I specify `-lnest3 -L/usr/local/lib` *explicite* and `/usr/local/lib/libnest3.a` contains the routine the linker whines about... Please, help a brother out! :)

EDIT: fixed typos

Comment: What is the *whole* link line?

Comment: You mentioned the C++ code was in a template class.  Was there ever an instantiation of it?

Comment: yes, there is an instantiation - that's why you see `MultiNestWrapper::Wrapper<double>`

Comment: As an aside, since the module procedure ABI is an implementation detail subject to change, you'd be better of using ISO_C_BINDING to create bindings to your Fortran procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order in which you specify libraries in GCC's command-line matters. Read GCC man pages for details - in short you have to specify libraries (`-lnest3` etc) **after** modules that use them. (I always specify libraries in the end of the command-line.)

In your case you have to write

```
gfortran ExampleLibMnCpp.o -o ExampleLibMnCpp -L/usr/local/lib -lstdc++ -llapack -lblas -lnest3
```

Comment: Yes, of course it does! Awww, shucks - such a rookie mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to specify the source files before the libraries when linking everything together. Like this:

```
gfortran *.o -lblas -l... ...
```

Linkers are sometimes picky about the order of their arguments.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm compelled to choose Serge's answer since he answered first, but nevertheless, thank you.