# Undefined reference ZGETRI/ZGETREF

Tags: fortran, lapack, matrix-inverse

I'm trying to create a complex matrix and compute its inverse using ZGETRI and ZGETREF from de Lapack  library.
Here's a test code of what I'm trying to do

```
module inversion_test

use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64

implicit none

real(dp), public, parameter :: wl = 1d0
real(dp), public, parameter :: wr = 1d0
integer, public, parameter :: matrix_size = 5

contains

function Green0inv(w) result(G0inv)
real(dp), intent(in) :: w
real(dp), dimension(matrix_size,matrix_size) :: Omega
complex(dp), dimension(matrix_size, matrix_size) :: Sigma
complex(dp),dimension(matrix_size,matrix_size) :: G0inv
integer :: i,j
complex(dp) :: S11, Snn
real(dp):: aux_wr1, aux_wl1


aux_wr1 = 1-w**2/(2d0*wr)
aux_wl1 = 1-w**2/(2d0*wl)

S11 = dcmplx(.5*(w**2-2d0*wl), 2.0*wL*dsqrt(1-aux_wL1**2))
Snn = dcmplx(.5*(w**2-2d0*wr), 2.0*wr*dsqrt(1-aux_wr1**2))

do i = 1,matrix_size
    do j=i,matrix_size
        Omega(i,j) = 0d0
        Omega(j,i) = Omega(i,j)
        Sigma(i,j) = dcmplx(0d0,0d0)
        Sigma(j,i) = Sigma(i,j)
    end do
end do

Sigma(1,1) = S11
Sigma(matrix_size,matrix_size) = Snn

do i = 1,matrix_size
    Omega(i,i) = w**2
end do


G0inv = Omega - Sigma

end function Green0inv

function Green0(w) result(G0)

implicit none

external liblapack

real(dp), intent(in) :: w
complex(dp), dimension(matrix_size,matrix_size) :: G0, Gaux
! Down here all these variables are needed by ZGETRF and ZGETRI
DOUBLE PRECISION, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: WORK     
Integer:: LWORK = matrix_size*matrix_size
Integer, Allocatable, dimension(:) :: IPIV
Integer :: INFO, LDA = matrix_size, M = matrix_size, N = matrix_size
Integer DeAllocateStatus



allocate(work(Lwork))
allocate(IPIV(N))

Gaux = Green0inv(w) 

CALL ZGETRF (M, N, Gaux, LDA, IPIV, INFO)
! This calculates LU descomposition of a matrix and overwrites it

CALL ZGETRI(N, Gaux, N, IPIV, WORK, LWORK, INFO)
! This calculates the inverse of a matrix knowing its LU descomposition and overwrites it


G0 = Gaux

DEALLOCATE (IPIV, STAT = DeAllocateStatus)
DEALLOCATE (WORK, STAT = DeAllocateStatus)


end function Green0

end module inversion_test

program test_inversion
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
use inversion_test

implicit none

complex(dp),dimension(matrix_size,matrix_size) :: G
real(dp) :: w

w = 1.0d0

G = Green0(w)

print*,G

end program test_inversion
```

But when I copile it as follows

```
gfortran -llapack test_inversion.f03 -o ti.out
```

I have this message

```
/tmp/ccxJ8QzV.o: In function `__inversion_test_MOD_green0':
test_inversion.f03:(.text+0x37a): undefined reference to `zgetrf_'
test_inversion.f03:(.text+0x3be): undefined reference to `zgetri_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea why this appears. I used this libraries outside of a module, that is in the main program, and nothing happens, but if I do this in such a way I have this message.

How can I solve this??

Edit: The solution provided by 
[Can't get past "undefined reference to `XXXX'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036158/cant-get-past-undefined-reference-to-xxxx)
works ok in my test program. But when it copiles but when I run I have this error message

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F3AA5CD5E08
#1  0x7F3AA5CD4F90
#2  0x7F3AA54074AF
#3  0x7FFD573AEED8
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

so I decided to run the following

```
gfortran fulltest1.f03 -g -fcheck=all -Wall
```

It gives several warnings. All say

Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

But it still appears

```
/tmp/ccUJiu8P.o: In function `__greenes_MOD_greenfrozen':
/home/danniel/fulltest1.f03:179: undefined reference to `zgetrf_'
/home/danniel/fulltest1.f03:179: undefined reference to `zgetri_'
/tmp/ccUJiu8P.o: In function `__greenes_MOD_green0':
/home/danniel/fulltest1.f03:143: undefined reference to `zgetrf_'
/home/danniel/fulltest1.f03:143: undefined reference to `zgetri_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And this error is the same as the one I have in my test program and I'm using the same module in both programs.

Comment: No need to repeat the tags in the question title.

Comment: @francescalus Right, but with the caveat that it is only necessary when linking a static library. The command the OP uses works for me unless I use `-static`.