# problem with HDF5 linking in Fortran with mpif90 compiler

Tags: linux, linker, fortran, hdf5

I'm running a fortran code for simulations and wanted to implement a subroutine which reads in a h5-file. Namely it's this EOSdriver with readtable.F90 (https://github.com/evanoconnor/EOSdriver).

I have installed the hdf5-library (with the mpif90 compiler) and when I compile and run EOSdriver on its own - it works fine. But then I changed the makefile of my simulation code by adding the EOSdriver-files. Added all the necessary HDF5-flags. When compiling there is no problem. When I try to link the files to use readtable in the simulation I somehow get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: readtable.o: in function `readtable_': readtable.F90:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `__h5lib_MOD_h5open_f'
/usr/bin/ld: readtable.F90:(.text+0x187): undefined reference to `__h5f_MOD_h5fopen_f'
/usr/bin/ld: readtable.F90:(.text+0x2aa): undefined reference to `__h5d_provisional_MOD_h5dread_integer_scalar'
/usr/bin/ld: readtable.F90:(.text+0x2ee): undefined reference to `__h5d_MOD_h5dopen_f'
/usr/bin/ld: readtable.F90:(.text+0x351): undefined reference to `__h5d_MOD_h5dclose_f'
/usr/bin/ld: readtable.F90:(.text+0x79e): undefined reference to `__h5_dble_interface_MOD_h5dread_double_3'
/usr/bin/ld: readtable.F90:(.text+0x115a): undefined reference to `__h5_dble_interface_MOD_h5dread_double_1'
/usr/bin/ld: readtable.F90:(.text+0x13ed): undefined reference to `__h5_dble_interface_MOD_h5dread_double_scalar'
/usr/bin/ld: readtable.F90:(.text+0x141a): undefined reference to `__h5f_MOD_h5fclose_f'
/usr/bin/ld: readtable.F90:(.text+0x1440): undefined reference to `__h5lib_MOD_h5close_f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The command to for linking I used is:

```
mpif90 -o ../relaxNS/relaxNS   -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8 -mcmodel=large -fopenmp -O3 -DEQMASS    -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local -lhdf5_fortran -lhdf5 -lz apply_PBC.o (all.o-files...) readtable.o
```

Do I need to use other hdf5-flags or what could be the issue here?

Comment: I suspect incorrect ordering of libraries relative to the object files that reference the symbols defined by the libraries.  Traditional linker behaviour requires library containing symbol definitions to follow object code containing symbol references.  If so - there are many duplicates - for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036158/cant-get-past-undefined-reference-to-xxxx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the actual library directory in your link line.

As in `-L/usr/local/lib`, so the full linking should be

```
mpif90 -o ../relaxNS/relaxNS   -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8 -mcmodel=large -fopenmp -O3 -DEQMASS    -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lhdf5_fortran -lhdf5 -lz apply_PBC.o (all.o-files...) readtable.o
```